# Find an element relative from a previous element

Tags: html, css, selenium, xpath, phpunit

I'm trying to find an element from a location I got before.
In easy words I use PHPUnit with Selenium/Mink/Behat and first did this

```
$products = $this->getPage()->findAll('css', 'ul.list li.item .price');
```

Now I have a list with all items that have a price.
From this position I have to go one node up and find the previous DIV-element.

```
/preceding-sibling::div[@class='product-box']/descendant-or-self::*/figure/descendant-or-self::*/a/@href
```

This all works with one XPATH call, but I can't do that in one call, because I have a condition that is checking my first call for a specific needle.

So in real I'm now at a price element and need to know how I can travel up to my previous DIV-element.

Comment: What does your input look like?

Comment: Hi Florent, what input do you mean? I have an unordered list as html structure. And inside the second div container is a content that I check to decide if that is the element I want. Otherwise I iterate to the next list item.
But if the element is correct I have to go to the first div container in that list item and from there two nodes down.

Comment: When you apply an XPath, you apply it to some input document.  What does it look like?  Give us an example.  Tell us what is your context node at the moment you apply the XPath, and what result you want, given that example.